# creating default set of users for a new site

Tags: wordpress

I will be creating numerous sites. Each site will have default users. These users are content creators i.e. having the ability to add and edit pages.

I want to save time by not having to recreate these users manually for every new site. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jons method will work if you want to share the users at all times, but if you just want to copy them from one to another, the easiest way is to create a SQL backup of the wp_users and wp_usermeta tables in phpmyadmin and then import them into each successive wordpress install.

Comment: doesn't WP3.0 have multisite capability?  I figured that meant 1 dashboard for multiple sites == a common set of admins for multiple sites.

Comment: Yes, it does. You can set extra "super admins" and they will automatically be admins on all sites. if you need to set "editors" and other ranks, I believe there is a plugin called "Simple user management for Wordpress MU" that makes it a lot easier to add people to multiple websites.

However, there are no "network editor" type ranks to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use a shared user table:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Custom_User_and_Usermeta_Tables

You should make one site the 'main' site. Then, whenever you make a new site, use the same database, but CHANGE THE PREFIX for each one. Then, define CUSTOM_USER_TABLE and CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE in wp-config.php so that it looks at your 'main' site's user tables. For example, say your main site is set with a database prefix of site1_, you would then, for site2_, add this to the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'site1_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'site1_usermeta' );
```

Comment: Would the new site share non-admin users?  This method looks like it will share all users.